# OpenCV 3.2 error when removing black background

Tags: java, opencv

I'm currently following this tutorial for image segmentation : http://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/07-image-segmentation.html.

I'm applying it to an image of a check.  I'm able to detect the edges, but I'm running into issues doing background removal.

My code:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    InputStream inputStream = this.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("check.jpg");
            image = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
 Mat colorImg = this.bufferedImageToMat(image);
        Mat grayImg = new Mat();
        Mat draw = new Mat();
        Mat frameImg = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(colorImg, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.blur(grayImg, colorImg, new Size(3, 3));
        Imgproc.Canny(grayImg, frameImg, 50, 150, 3, false);
        frameImg.convertTo(draw, CvType.CV_8U);

      Mat fg= this.doBackgroundRemoval(frameImg);

}
 private Mat doBackgroundRemoval(Mat frame) throws Exception{
        // init

        Mat hsvImg = new Mat();
        List<Mat> hsvPlanes = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat thresholdImg = new Mat();

        // threshold the image with the histogram average value
        System.out.println(frame.type());
        hsvImg.create(frame.size(),CvType.CV_8U);

        BufferedImage image = this.Mat2BufferedImage(hsvImg);

        Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, hsvImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV); //**** THIS IS WHERE IT BLOWS UP
        Core.split(hsvImg, hsvPlanes);

        double threshValue = this.getHistAverage(hsvImg, hsvPlanes.get(0));

        Imgproc.threshold(hsvPlanes.get(0), thresholdImg, threshValue, 179.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    /*    else
            Imgproc.threshold(hsvPlanes.get(0), thresholdImg, threshValue, 179.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
*/
        Imgproc.blur(thresholdImg, thresholdImg, new Size(5, 5));

        // dilate to fill gaps, erode to smooth edges
        Imgproc.dilate(thresholdImg, thresholdImg, new Mat(), new Point(-1, 1), 6);
        Imgproc.erode(thresholdImg, thresholdImg, new Mat(), new Point(-1, 1), 6);

        Imgproc.threshold(thresholdImg, thresholdImg, threshValue, 179.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);

        // create the new image
        Mat foreground = new Mat(frame.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, new Scalar(255, 255, 255));
        frame.copyTo(foreground, thresholdImg);

        return foreground;
    }
```

when we get up to  Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, hsvImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV) in the doBackgroundRemoval method, I get this error:

```
**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 9815
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win64-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:9815: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cv::cvtColor**
```

Is there anyway I can fix this? Or an alternative way to remove the background?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `frame.type()` and `frame.channels()` yield?

Comment: You may have to add the picture 'check.jpg' to the post so we can reproduce your error.

Comment: @DanielR type = 0 and channels = 1

Comment: @bfris I'm using an image of my check. Not too comfortable putting it up. But I took a picture of it with my iphone if that helps

Comment: Oh. It's a picture of a bank check. You should be able to edit it to remove all sensitive information. From your error message though, it does look to be a problem with color depth along the lines @Daniel R. has suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide a colored image to the `doBackgroundRemoval(Mat frame)` method. You are providing a grayscale image with `this.doBackgroundRemoval(frameImg)` in your main function which does not work with the implentation of `doBackgroundRemoval(Mat frame)`.